# Derivative of ln

Tags: derivatives

Can you help me find the mistake? I am searching so long but cant find it. I am so frustrated....
$$\ln(uv)= \ln(u)+\ln(v)$$
$$\frac{d}{d( u v)}\ln(uv)=\frac{d}{d( uv)}\ln(u)+\frac{d}{d(uv)}\ln(v)$$
$$\frac{d}{d( u v)}\ln(uv)=\frac{d}{d(uv)}\ln(uv/v)+\frac{d}{d(uv)}\ln(vu/u)$$
$$\frac{1}{uv}=\frac{1}{uv/v}\frac{1}{v}+\frac{1}{vu/u}\frac{1}{u}$$
$$\frac{1}{uv}=\frac{1}{uv}+\frac{1}{uv}=\frac{2}{uv}$$

Comment: A note about notation: you should write $\frac{d}{d (uv)}$.

Comment: Okay. I Edited it

Comment: $\frac{d}{d(uv)}\ln(u)$ isn't well-defined.

Comment: Here's a simpler one:
$$1 = \frac{\partial}{\partial(uv)}(uv) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial(uv)}v + u\frac{\partial v}{\partial(uv)} = 0v + u0 = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

The error is going from $$ \frac { \mathrm d } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } \ln ( u v / v ) $$ to $$ \frac 1 { u v / v } \frac 1 v \text , $$ and similarly for $ \ln ( u v / u ) $.  This is because $ v $ and $ u $ are not constant (or at least, they might not be, and if they both are then so is $ u v $, and then differentiating with respect to $ u v $ doesn't make sense).

If we do this step more slowly, applying the Quotient Rule, we get
$$ \eqalign { \frac { \mathrm d } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } \ln ( u v / v ) & = \frac 1 { u v / v } \frac { \mathrm d } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } ( u v / v ) \\
& = \frac 1 { u v / v } \frac { v \, \frac { \mathrm d } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } ( u v ) - u v \, \frac { \mathrm d } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } v } { v ^ 2 } \\
& = \frac 1 { u v / v } \frac { v \, 1 - u v \, \frac { \mathrm d v } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } } { v ^ 2 } \\
& = \frac 1 { u v / v } \frac { 1 - u \, \frac { \mathrm d v } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } } v \\
& = \frac 1 { u v } \biggl ( 1 - u \, \frac { \mathrm d v } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } \biggr ) \\
& = \frac 1 { u v } - \frac 1 v \, \frac { \mathrm d v } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } \ne \frac 1 { u v } \text . } $$
Now, you might think that $ \mathrm d v / \mathrm d ( u v ) = 0 $, but that would be a lot like saying that $ \mathrm d ( u v ) / \mathrm d v = u $, and that would be a contradiction right there (since they should be reciprocals).  You can use *partial* derivatives and say that $ \partial v / \partial ( u v ) = 0 $, but you need to have a conistent set of independent variables to do that (or indicate which variable is held fixed each time), and you can't consistently have both $ \partial v / \partial ( u v ) = 0 $ (to simplify one term) and $ \partial u / \partial ( u v ) = 0 $ (to simplify the other term), since $ u $, $ v $, and $ u v $ aren't all independent.

Anyway, if we do the calculation above for both terms and add them together, then we get $$ \eqalign { \frac { \mathrm d } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } \ln ( u v ) & = 
\frac { \mathrm d } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } \ln ( u v / v ) + \frac { \mathrm d } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } \ln ( u v / u ) \\ &
= \frac 1 { u v } - \frac 1 v \, \frac { \mathrm d v } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } + \frac 1 { u v } - \frac 1 u \, \frac { \mathrm d u } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } \\ &
= \frac 1 { u v } - \frac 1 { u v } \, \frac { u \, \mathrm d v } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } + \frac 1 { u v } - \frac 1 { u v } \, \frac { v \, \mathrm d u } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } \\ &
= \frac 2 { u v } - \frac 1 { u v } \, \frac { u \, \mathrm d v + v \, \mathrm d u } { \mathrm d ( u v ) } \\ &
= \frac 2 { u v } - \frac 1 { u v } \cdot 1 = \frac 1 { u v } \text , } $$
because $ u \, \mathrm d v + v \, \mathrm d u = \mathrm d ( u v ) $.

Answer (score 0):

> $$\ln(uv)= \ln(u)+\ln(v)$$

This is correct for $u,v>0.$

> $$\frac{d}{d( u v)}\ln(uv)=\frac{d}{d( uv)}\ln(u)+\frac{d}{d(uv)}\ln(v)$$

The terms on the right hand side are not well-defined.

> $$\frac{d}{d( u v)}\ln(uv)=\frac{d}{d(uv)}\ln(uv/v)+\frac{d}{d(uv)}\ln(vu/u)$$

This rewrite of the right hand side would be valid were the right hand side well-defined.

> $$\frac{1}{uv}=\frac{1}{uv/v}\frac{1}{v}+\frac{1}{vu/u}\frac{1}{u}$$

Here you have suddenly used a partial derivative w.r.t. $uv$.

> $$\frac{1}{uv}=\frac{1}{uv}+\frac{1}{uv}=\frac{2}{uv}$$

This simplification of the last result is valid, but remember that we have had a couple of problems before.

Answer (score -1):

You have two variables $u$ and $v$, so it's not clear what you mean by a derivative with respect to $uv$ for something that is not a function of $uv$.